# Codenameone: Query regarding to suspended mode

Tags: codenameone

we want to start application from initial stage when we put it in suspended mode or minimize it.currently when i minimizing application it starts from screen where i left or application starts from that screen the screen which present at the time of minimizing application.
we just want to start application from initial state or specific screen when we minimize it or we put it into suspended mode.

Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an application is minimized we call `stop()` and when it's restored we call `start()` again. Just remove the boilerplate code that calls `current.show()` in the `start()` method and state won't be restored.